# How to change the background color of the top menu dynamically?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I am developing the website on python(Django). I am getting some difficulties to change the background color of the top menu on every page.

What I am doing is, I have an `index.html` page and `templates` which are `aboutus, contactus` and `service`. When I am on the `home` page then I am getting the gray background of the menu which is correct. Now I am on aboutus and I have to change the menu color from gray to black but I am getting the only gray.

So I want to know how do I change the class or override the CSS? Should I need to add the class to the body and then override the menu BG? How do I added the class to the body on each page dynamically?

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title%}Home{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="Wrpper">
    <header class="bg_gray"><!--top menu code--></header>
    {% block content %}
    <!-- template code -->
    {% endblock %}

    <footer><!--footer code--></footer>

</div>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
 .bg_gray{background-color: #ccc;}
 .bg_black{background-color: #000;}
```

**aboutus.html** (All template are same)

```
{% extends 'demo1/index.html' %}
{% load static %}
<title>{% block title %}About us{% endblock %}</title>
{% block content %}
<!--some code here-->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the header's class using javascript

first give your header an id :

then include the javascript file:

 in app.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            
                $('#top-header').removeClass('bg_gray');
                $('#top-header').addClass('bg_blak');
                 
             
        });
```

```html
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/app.js' %}">

<header class="bg_gray" id="top-header"><!--top menu code--></header>
```

Comment: No, This will not work. If I am on the home page then it will override the from bg_gray to bg_blak that I don't want on home page

Comment: Am not familiar with Django but if am developing for front-end i would create a sumple js function for each page to inject css class

Comment: but the above answer will not work on all the pages. If  I add id top-header then it will display on all the pages...correct? and according to your scrip, it will change the background color bg_gray to bg_blak.

Answer (score 0):

Give important to bg_black class it will override the css of bg_gray class property...

like this,

```
.bg_black{
background-color: #000!important;
}
```

html:

```
<header class="bg_gray bg_black"><!--top menu code--></header>
```

Comment: How can I add .bg_black  to the header menu?

Comment: This will not work. If I add class name then it will display on all the pages...correct? and according to your HTML, it will change the background color bg_gray to bg_blak. I have only one top menu on my index.html page and that menu will display on all the pages. If I add bg_black then it will affect other pages too.

Comment: Okay I thought your header code is in about page also.

Comment: I have only one file called index.html with menu, footer and body code which I am displaying dynamically.